# Django - Loading Robots.txt through generic views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, robots.txt

I have uploaded robots.txt into my templates directory on my production server. I am using generic views;

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

(r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
```

However, when I load robots.txt on the browser I get a 404 - Page not found.

Can someone suggest what needs to be done to fix this. Thanks.

I should point out that on the local environment this seems to be working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally got it. I had to add a '/' in ^robots.txt$

```
(r'^robots\.txt/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),
```

That's elementary! I presumed that by default APPEND_SLASH it True however, on the production server it didn't work.

Let me know if anyone can provide some insights on it.

Comment: Using `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your app's settings fixes that without having to add a trailing slash to your URL. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH